# PHPMetrics option --excluded-dirs="myfolder" : myfolder dir is not excluded within docker

Tags: php, docker

I'm trying to use PHPMetrics within Docker image.

I run the next command in the project root folder:

```
docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/project jolicode/phaudit phpmetrics --report-html=var/artefacts/phpmetrics --excluded-dirs="myfolder" /project
```

It works fine and the report is correctly generated, but the option excluded-dirs is not interpreted. All PHP class files in the folder "myfolder" are in the HTML report...

The vendor directory is correctly excluded by default.

I've tried without success:

```
--excluded-dirs='myfolder'
--excluded-dirs=myfolder
--excluded-dirs="./myfolder"
--excluded-dirs="myfolder/"
--excluded-dirs="project/myfolder"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add the exclude into the command as show below the additional parameter:

```
vendor/bin/phpmetrics --report-html=report_folder/ project/ --exclude="lib"
```

Its working fine for me. You can comma seperate the excludes too, e.g.

```
--exclude="lib","data","storage"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it helps! This one is working `docker run --rm -v pwd:/project jolicode/phaudit phpmetrics --report-html=var/artefacts/phpmetrics /project --exclude="folder1","folder2"`